# Unable to resolve dependency 'html5shiv'

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

please help me to resolve this error:

```
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
Attempting to resolve dependency 'twitter.bootstrap.mvc4'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'html5shiv'.
Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'html5shiv'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

i want to install **twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.samplen.nupkg** offline.i add folder path to nuget manager in vs2012.
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `Install-Package html5shiv` first

Comment: you mean i try to install from nuget.org?

Comment: go to the package manger console in visual studio and type that

Comment: i don't have internet and want to use nuget offline.

Comment: that's what is probably causing the error in the first place.  As it can't down load the dependency. Can you not get temporary internet access on your development machine? I am not sure how you can install packages offline never done it

Comment: This article will help for offline package installation http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx  you still need the html5shiv package though first